# How to truncate all tables using a SQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, plpgsql, ibatis

I am trying to run the sql script from my java code to truncate all the tables from particular database. I am using apache-ibatis-3.5.13 which have a script runner class. It seems to be not working with PLSQL script. Here is the script:

```
-- @DELIMITER $
do
$$
DECLARE row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='public'
    AND table_name NOT IN ('admins', 'admin_roles')
    AND table_catalog='my_db' 
  LOOP 
    EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I CONTINUE IDENTITY RESTRICT;',row.table_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
-- @DELIMITER $
```

My java code is like that:

```
public static void resetDB(SqlConnection conn, URL url) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            if (conn.isConnected()) {
                PrintWriter logWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            PrintWriter errorLogWriter = new PrintWriter(System.err);

            ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn.getConnection());
            sr.setStopOnError(true);
            sr.setDelimiter("]");
            sr.setLogWriter(logWriter);
            sr.setErrorLogWriter(errorLogWriter);

            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(url.getFile())));
            // Running the script
            sr.setSendFullScript(true);
            sr.runScript(reader);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is no exception or error is showing when i run this script and data is still in the tables. I have another solution where i can call the select query from information_schema.tables and then run the truncate query from java but not liking the idea and really wants to do it via sql script.
Any one have idea about it?

Comment: Remove `sr.setStopOnError(false);`. Add an `ErrorLogWriter` and a `LogWriter`. Don't assume everything is running without an error when you **explicitly** disable error reporting.

Comment: sr.setStopOnError(false); Is it not ok to set it false

As per documentation If we not set both setLogWriter and setErrorLogWriter it will dump on System.out.

Comment: You ***want*** it to stop on any errors and tell you about them.

Comment: Yes, if i make some error statement in my script it will stop executing it and bark for sql syntax error. So with correct script it is executing but doing nothing.

Comment: I have now made a changes as you said(check the code in the main question)but still nothing interesting has been printing out on console except the running script file sql.